# Maximum length of [NSXMLNode stringValue]

Tags: xml, cocoa, nsstring, nsxml

I have an XML document which contains an element that is over 90,000 characters in length<sup>*</sup>.

```
NSXMLNode* node = ...;
NSString* val = [node stringValue]; // this is not the full contents of the node!
```

The second line only gives me 80k or so. This is obviously not what I want, so I'd appreciate some suggestions. Is NSXMLNode broken? I'd guess that I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance!

<sup>*</sup> i know that 90kbytes in an element is not great, this is out of my hands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does `[node objectValue]` give you?

Comment: Thanks Alex,

I can't spot the difference between the [node stringValue] and [node objectValue] when the return is string. How did you know about this?

Comment: I'm curious, but did this help? I wasn't sure from your question.

Nonetheless, I looked at the NSXMLNode class reference at: http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLNode_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: It did, thanks.

From the docs, it seems like objectValue would be the same as stringValue. I guess it's not. Puzzling.

Comment: If you have a moment, you might file a bug with http://bugreporter.apple.com -- that might help Apple fix this or at least point to them that they should clarify whatever restriction is on [node stringValue].